# Реализация синглтона с многократным освобождением ресурсов

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Как правильно реализовать многопоточный синглтон с возможностью в любой момент и из любой нити освободить все занятые ресурсы и так чтобы при следующем запросе они снова лениво разворачивались.

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы опубликовали собственные попытки решить задачу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Да, я знаю, просто некогда было на сайт зайти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чём проблема? Ну окружите весь доступ мьютексом. Поскольку вам нужна логика реинициализации, простое решение с `Lazy<T>`-свойствами не проходит.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    // классическая реализация из статьи Jon Skeet'а
    // http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton() { }

    /////////////////// ленивые свойства ///////////////////
    object accessMutex = new object();

    string lazyProperty;
    public string LazyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            lock (accessMutex)
                return lazyProperty ?? (lazyProperty = CreateLazyProperty());
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (accessMutex)
        {
            lazyProperty = null;
            // обнулите остальные свойства, освободите IDisposable-ресурсы
        }
    }

    string CreateLazyProperty() { ... }
}
```